# Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.dokka']

Tags: java, gradle, springsource

when I was trying to improt gradle project (spring-framework-master) to eclipse then Appear this error informations :
what I hava down

---

### the first step :

### gradlew cleanIdea :spring-oxm:compileTestJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\spring-framework-master\build.gradle' line: 15
- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.dokka', version: '0.9.17']

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.dokka']
  >   Could not generate a proxy class for class org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

### BUILD FAILED in 0s

gradle -v

---

### Gradle 4.8.1

Build time:   2018-06-21 07:53:06 UTC
Revision:     0abdea078047b12df42e7750ccba34d69b516a22

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_20 (Oracle Corporation 25.20-b23)

### OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64

```
gradlew cleanIdea :spring-oxm:compileTestJava -stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\spring-framework-master\build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.dokka', version: '0.9.17']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.dokka']
   > Could not generate a proxy class for class org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.dokka', version: '0.9.17']
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.exceptionOccurred(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:247)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:229)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:148)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:184)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:66)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:37)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:677)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:138)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:262)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:175)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.dokka']
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:149)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:124)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$3.run(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:151)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:225)
        ... 100 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:228)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.create(TaskFactory.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.createTask(DefaultTaskContainer.java:248)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:237)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:232)
        at org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaPlugin.apply(main.kt:32)
        at org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaPlugin.apply(main.kt:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$200(DefaultPluginManager.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:251)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:143)
        ... 103 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 302
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/jetbrains/dokka/gradle/DokkaTask.generate()V @355: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 1302 ceb8 02d3 59c6 0006 a700 0757 1302
    0x0000010: d54c 1302 ce13 02d5 b802 d957 002a b602
    0x0000020: db2a b602 dd3a 0419 04b6 02e0 4d19 04b6
    0x0000030: 02e2 4e2a b600 173a 042a b702 e5c0 0055
    0x0000040: 2a2d c000 4eb7 02e7 c000 4eb8 024c 3a05
    0x0000050: 1905 b902 ea01 0099 0018 2ab6 0039 1302
    0x0000060: ecb9 0041 0200 1302 ce2b b802 d957 b12a
    0x0000070: b702 efc0 0055 2cc0 004e b802 4cc0 0055
    0x0000080: 2ab4 00ca b802 4c3a 06b2 01f1 59c7 0006
    0x0000090: b802 8a13 02f1 b600 353a 0719 0759 1302
    0x00000a0: f3b8 001f b602 f759 1302 f9b8 001f c002
    0x00000b0: fbb8 02ff c003 0103 bd00 69b6 0304 3a08
    0x00000c0: 2ab6 006d b603 0559 1303 07b8 001f 3a0a
    0x00000d0: 1908 5913 0309 b800 1f3a 0b19 0a13 030b
    0x00000e0: 190b b803 1159 c700 0ebb 01f3 5913 0313
    0x00000f0: b701 f6bf c003 0b3a 09bb 0315 592a b400
    0x0000100: a719 06c0 004e 3a0b 3a16 3a15 3a14 190b
    0x0000110: 3a0c bb00 5059 190b 100a b802 29b7 022b
    0x0000120: c000 553a 0d19 0cb9 0059 0100 3a0e 190e
    0x0000130: b900 5f01 0099 0031 190e b900 6301 003a
    0x0000140: 0f19 0d19 0fc0 01de 3a10 3a17 1910 5912
    0x0000150: 67b8 001f b603 183a 1819 1719 18b9 0077
    0x0000160: 0200 57a7 ffcb 190d c000 793a 1719 1419
    0x0000170: 1519 1619 1719 052a b400 dec0 004e b802
    0x0000180: 18c0 004e 3a0b 3a18 3a17 3a16 3a15 3a14
    0x0000190: 190b 3a0c bb00 5059 190b 100a b802 29b7
    0x00001a0: 022b c000 553a 0d19 0cb9 0059 0100 3a0e
    0x00001b0: 190e b900 5f01 0099 0036 190e b900 6301
    0x00001c0: 003a 0f19 0d19 0f3a 103a 1919 0419 10b9
    0x00001d0: 031c 0200 5913 031e b800 1fb6 0318 3a1a
    0x00001e0: 1919 191a b900 7702 0057 a7ff c619 0dc0
    0x00001f0: 0079 3a19 1914 1915 1916 1917 1918 1919
    0x0000200: 2ab4 00d0 c000 4eb8 0218 c000 4e3a 0b3a
    0x0000210: 193a 183a 173a 163a 153a 1419 0b3a 0cbb
    0x0000220: 0050 5919 0b10 0ab8 0229 b702 2bc0 0055
    0x0000230: 3a0d 190c b900 5901 003a 0e19 0eb9 005f
    0x0000240: 0100 9900 3619 0eb9 0063 0100 3a0f 190d
    0x0000250: 190f 3a10 3a1a 1904 1910 b903 1c02 0059
    0x0000260: 1303 1eb8 001f b603 183a 1b19 1a19 1bb9
    0x0000270: 0077 0200 57a7 ffc6 190d c000 793a 1a19
    0x0000280: 1419 1519 1619 1719 1819 1919 1a2a b400
    0x0000290: b62a b400 b12a b400 fc03 2ab4 0112 2ab4
    0x00002a0: 0107 2ab4 0102 2ab4 00e4 042a b400 d8c0
    0x00002b0: 0079 2ab4 0132 2ab4 012c 2ab4 0138 2ab4
    0x00002c0: 013d 2ab4 0144 2a19 05b6 0320 2ab4 0149
    0x00002d0: 2ab4 014e b703 233a 0a19 09bb 0325 592a
    0x00002e0: b703 28c0 032a 190a b803 30b9 0334 0300
    0x00002f0: 1909 b903 3601 0013 02ce 2bb8 02d9 57a7
    0x0000300: 000e 4d13 02ce 2bb8 02d9 572c bfb1
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [28, 102] => handler: 770
    bci [111, 759] => handler: 770
    bci [770, 771] => handler: 770
  Stackmap Table:
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@13,Object[#538])
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@17,Object[#538])
    full_frame(@111,{Object[#2],Object[#538],Object[#627],Object[#121],Object[#33],Object[#121]},{})
    full_frame(@147,{Object[#2],Object[#538],Object[#627],Object[#121],Object[#33],Object[#121],Object[#121]},{Object[#49]})
    full_frame(@244,{Object[#2],Object[#538],Object[#627],Object[#121],Object[#33],Object[#121],Object[#121],Object[#111],Object[#105],Top,Object[#49],Object[#105]},{Object[#105]})
    full_frame(@302,{Object[#2],Object[#538],Object[#627],Object[#121],Object[#33],Object[#121],Object[#121],Object[#111],Object[#105],Object[#779],Object[#49],Object[#78],Object[#78],Object[#85],Object[#91],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Uninitialized[#249],Uninitialized[#249],Object[#538]},{})
    same_frame(@358)
    append_frame(@432,Object[#121],Object[#121])
    same_frame(@493)
    append_frame(@571,Object[#121])
    same_frame(@632)
    full_frame(@770,{Object[#2],Object[#538]},{Object[#397]})
    full_frame(@781,{Object[#2],Object[#538],Object[#627],Object[#121],Object[#33],Object[#121],Object[#121],Object[#111],Object[#105],Object[#779],Object[#789],Object[#78],Object[#78],Object[#85],Object[#91],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#789],Object[#789],Object[#538],Object[#121],Object[#121],Object[#121],Object[#121]},{})

        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspectClass(ClassInspector.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.visitGraph(ClassInspector.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspect(ClassInspector.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.inspectType(AbstractClassGenerator.java:288)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.inspectType(AbstractClassGenerator.java:243)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:115)
        ... 122 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the "build.gradle" file then change version: '0.9.17' to '0.9.15'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case a newly added plugin was not compatible with the used gradle version (`4.0`). Updated gradle-version of `./gradlew` in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to `6.0` did the trick.